# Steam Bending American Walnut

Tags: steam-bending

I asked this on the Home Improvement and it was suggested I ask here too.

We have a bay window which has an actual curve to it rather than the half octogan that some have.

We have skirting boarded the rest of the room in American Walnut and trying to determine how to bend it into a curve. The walnut has been pre-oiled.

I am not comfortable in kerf cuts as this is the only piece of remaining walnut that covers the span. If I ruin this piece then I will have to probably go with two pieces in the bay as it took several weeks to get this wood and carpet fitting is rapidly approaching.

Currently I have it suspended between two stacks of books which I am slowly loading with tubs of water to bend it.

I was thinking of raising it further off the floor, draping towels over the edges and putting a food steamer underneath and running it to aid/speed up the bending.

Will this aid me or is it likely to ruin the wood?

Wood dimensions are: The thickest edge is 20mm and the thinnest is 5mm. The span is 2.5m and height is 150mm. The website I bought this from is https://www.britishhardwoods.co.uk/lambs-tongue-black-walnut-skirting-board.html
[image]

Comment: I've never done it myself, but I can only imagine that adding steam to your setup is what will actually make it "steam bending". As you're doing it now is just "warping". I'd think you've got a better chance of breaking/splitting the wood doing it dry than you would if it were wet/steamed. Again, no actual experience, just thinking out loud... Also, watch those stacks of books - easy for them to slip apart, the wood fall, the water dump everywhere. Ruin the books at a minimum, I'd think.

Comment: The tubs have lids on them and there are towels underneath.

Comment: IF the curve is somewhat shallow, it might be possible to build up this profile by creating three separate pieces laminated together.  The back 5mm piece extends from floor to top and could be bent to the curve with the middle round top portion glued to it and finally the beveled front portion.

Comment: *"Currently I have it suspended between two stacks of books which I am slowly loading with tubs of water to bend it."* You're going to end up snapping it unless the curvature you're after is exceptionally shallow? If it isn't I would strongly recommend you halt that attempt sooner rather than later, unless you introduce water (lots of it, and hot) into the mix somehow, or better, actually smother it in steam as in conventional steam bending. The minor addition of some steam from a steamer is perhaps only of help with wood at near veneer thicknesses, q.v. bending for violin making.

Comment: I went ahead with the food steamer and towels. Running the steamer for an hour a day with 12.5kg at the centre point. It is slow going. Yesterday I got about a 2cm drop from when I started to when the steamer switched off, however it sprung back by about 1cm as it dried.

Comment: I myself has very little experience with bending wood, so I would recommend watching and listening to someone who has a lot of experience - Mr.Engels in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pPKUgpn0CI where he explains common mistakes and problems with steam bending.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t have a ton of experience steam bending, so take this for what it’s worth.

Any bending of wood that’s already been dried (kiln is worse than air) is going to be harder to bend. The oil finish isn’t going to help.

If actual bending has any hope, I think you actually need to build a steam box. Overcurve the form a bit to allow for springback.

A couple of alternatives come to mind. Kerfing and curving might work, but if your skirting has a profile (sounds like it does), that might be rough. Cutting the profiled section off the flat section might be workable (since the thinner profile section might be convinced to curve without much kerfing).

You might also consider a kerfed board that’s veneered with a thin layer of the flat section of your skirting. You probably need a bandsaw to harvest that veneer (and separate the profiled section). Or just buy walnut veneer, though that’ll be really thin.

Comment: +1. At least the OP is in the UK so if the wood is up to equilibrium it'll have a substantially higher MC than is normal for the US :-) Just one quick point about the oil finish not helping, pretty much all oil finishes offer so little protection from water vapour penetration that it's not worth mentioning. Even built up it's not much, but with just a light application (likely in this case, could easily be just one coat) it's basically zero.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with the food steamer placed under the board with weights placed in the middle. Eventually got to 18kg. Finally after removing from the weight it was left with 8cm of bend which will have to do as the carpet fitters are coming.  Here is a photo of the early setup.  Once the additional weight went on I had to raise the two stands with more books as the towel was resting on the back of the steamer.

[image: Early test of steam bending]